# java: I want to know the primitive datatype of input which is stored in String variable

Tags: java, variables, casting

```
String x;
x=scanner.nextLine();
```

I entered 1 or 6.66.
It should give output as `int` or `double`/`float`. whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of parsing the result of `scanner.nextLine()` which returns a `String`, you should instead use the convenience methods of the `Scanner` class like `hasNextInt()` and `hasNextFloat()`.

For example the following code should do what you expect :

```
if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
    System.out.println("float");
    float myValue = scanner.nextFloat();
    // do something with the float myValue
}else if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("int")
    int myValue = scanner.nextInt();
    // do something with the int myValue
} else { // fallback on string
    String myValue = scanner.next();
    // do something with the string myValue
}
```

Comment: can java automatically determine the type of input (int/double) i have given in the string, how can i achieve that?

Comment: @deepakahuja If you want to determine it by yourself then you can use regex to see if the String contains only of numbers, has a decimal point etc. Or you just use the Scanner class as Aaron shows in his answer

Comment: @deepakahuja a String is a String. For example "10/10/2016 00:00:00" is a String that really looks like a Date. However, maybe I have defined some strange class that would parse it as one of it instances. So which is it? the date, or the custom class? Java can't assert that.

Comment: @Mike using regexs here wouldn't be a good idea as it probably would disregard localization, and you would still have to "code" something for each type you expect. Java provides functions to check whether an instance could be parsed as a specific class, in this case Integer.parseInt() and Float.parseFloat()